# how to filter text using grep of logs files

Tags: shell, scripting

I have two file with names like

```
DNSM***.log
DNSM****.log
NSM***.log
NSM*****.log
```

I want to filter out only files with `NSM` starting word and output in output txt file.

Following I tried.

```
grep -i DNSM > out.txt
```

But i am getting out listing files with both `DNSM` and `NSM`.

Please help.

Comment: Your example is wrong, there's no data source so grep is indefinitely waiting for something to filter. If you need to grep only NSM and DNSM you can do something like this:
```ls | grep -i 'NSM\|DNSM'```

Comment: actually i have provided data source. ls -lrtX | grep -i DNSM > out.txt  StefanF, your solution giving me same unwanted result.

Comment: i want either DNSM or NSM

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
grep '^NSM.*' > out.txt
```

Which will produce output as

```
NSM***.log
NSM*****.log
```

Explanation

`^` asserts the pattern `NSM` at the begining of the line

`.*` matches any number of character after `NSM`

Comment: hi Nu11p01n73R, this is not giving any op